# Pinescript function for checking if price has crossed line in the past

Tags: line, linear-regression, pine-script, pine-script-v5

Does pinescript have any built in functions to check if a line has been crossed in the past? The line would be repainting as I am looking to check if a linear regression channel's deviation lines have been crossed previously or not, but more specifically the number of times crossed to attempt to validate it's strength.

This code will work, although the code execution time is very slow:

```
priceFound = 0
countAbove = 0
countBelow = 0
length = 100
slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)    //Calculates slope of using line coordinates
for i = 0 to length
    priceFound := slope*((_y1/slope) + bar_index[i] - _x1)        //Calculates price at y-coord
    countAbove := high[i]>priceFound ? countAbove+1 : countAbove  //Checks if above
    countBelow := low[i]<priceFound ? countBelow+1 : countBelow   //Checks if below
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is checking on every single newly created bar 100 bars back if price was above/below your coordinate. Yes it's not really efficient, though I don't think simple arithmetic operations would challenge pine script. (Of course I can be wrong)
Instead you could try another direction with [ta.crossunder()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossunder) / [ta.crossover()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossover) or ta.cross(). With these you wouldn't need slope calculation or whatsoever because you can check your plot value and the high/low real time (or rather on bar close). Of course this way you would only find out if your line did not hold and you would build up your strength tracking the opposite way.
Still, I think it's worth considering as a solution to your problem.